# Ajax - Data not uploading to my dropdown list only space is comming there

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'DemarcationFilterServlet',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {datastr: catId},
    success: function (json) {
        $.each(json, function(index, text) { 
            $('#selDemId').append(  
                $('<option></option>').val(index).html(text)       
            );
        });
    }
});

// selDemId is my dropdown
// return index val show as a 0
```

Comment: I believe that the 'text' in 'function(index, text)' is undefined here. Is your json an object or array?

Comment: It is  ARRAY list

Answer (score 0):

Refer to $.each([each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)), it does not receive the second parameter here. So the `text` is undefined here.

If the response is an object:

```
    $.each(json, function(idx) { 
        $('#selDemId').append(  
            $('<option></option>').val(idx).html(json[idx])       
        );
    });
```

If the response is a collection like [{ index: 1, text: 'text' }]

```
    $.each(json, function(idx) { 
        $('#selDemId').append(  
            $('<option></option>').val(json[idx].index).html(json[idx].text)       
        );
    });
```

Comment: Thankx for helping me, I tried  with this  coder  and  it  still  it  is  not  corrected,  I have uploaded data to bean  through  the servlet and particuler  data need  to  be added to  drop  down. Servlet  pass data  to  bean correctly.

Comment: pntcatId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("datastr"));
            List<DemarcationEntity> e = new DemarcationLogicInput().getDemLevel(pntcatId); 
             json = new Gson().toJson(e);
  response.setContentType("application/json");
  response.getWriter().write(json);
                System.out.println("json - "+json);

Comment: pntcatId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("datastr"));
            List<DemarcationEntity> e = new DemarcationLogicInput().getDemLevel(pntcatId); 
json = new Gson().toJson(e);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(json);
System.out.println("json - "+json);